# ¿Por qué se pierde el acceso a colas de revisión cuando se alcanza el límite diario de votos?

Tags: soporte, colas-de-revisión

Cuando se alcanza el límite diario de votos a favor o en contra, se pierde acceso a algunas colas de revisión, y en particular a las colas de:

- Primeras publicaciones
- Respuestas tardías

¿Por qué ocurre eso? Comprendo que no se puede votar a favor o en contra, pero aún se podrían realizar otras acciones útiles como editar, comentar o reportar, que también son importantes.

Comment: Supongo que se hace para que nadie "acapare". Limitando el número de revisiones que hace cada persona permite que haya más rotación y más puntos de vista. Creo que es bueno. Si tienes muchas ganas de hacerlo igualmente, con tu nivel de reputación puedes entrar en el historial de las revisiones para ver el listado de publicaciones que van entrando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sin poder votar a favor, no estás en condiciones de revisar esas colas eficientemente.

Los votos positivos a usuarios nuevos son sumamente importantes para fomentar la participación. Es uno de los resultados más relevantes de esas revisiones: cuando una pregunta está bien formulada (demuestra trabajo de investigación / es útil / es clara), se debe votar +1. Es totalmente coherente que no puedas revisarlas cuando no te quedan más votos.

Creo entender tu punto: un revisor responsable podría omitir los casos que se debería votar +1. Sin embargo, también están los casos en los que corresponden dos acciones, por ejemplo editar y votar. En esa situación, dejar que alguien sin votos revise esas publicaciones sería tendencioso, haciendo que ocurran revisiones "*incompletas*", donde el mayor perjudicado es el autor de la publicación.

Tomando estos puntos en consideración, creo que es lógico que no tengas acceso.